# Long load time after server response

Tags: html, css, asp.net, firebug

I am developing a website with ASP.NET Web Forms and am currently trying to improve some performance issues. According to Firebug the server responds after about 3 seconds (not great but acceptable for now), however the page is done loading and displayed after about 6 seconds (`onload` more than 8 seconds).

Firebug's *Net* panel shows combined loading times of just a bit more than 3 seconds. However there are some pauses that you guys can help me understand.

[image: Firebug's *Net* panel showing long load time]

In the screenshot you can see the load times within the *Net* panel. You can see the CSS files at the bottom are being loaded from cache, but there is a pause before and after them being loaded before the page load is complete.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up and especially to remove those "pauses"?

Edit: Some additional information:

- As you can see in the screenshot I do not have a copy of the jQuery and jQuery UI libs on my machine. They will be downloaded from the Google CDN if necessary, however in this case they are being loaded from cache.
- I put all JavaScript files besides jQuery and jQuery UI to the bottom of the `<body>` element.
- I minified and combined all the CSS files without noticing a difference.

Comment: Weird! I've only seen this behavior once before. Does your javascript files do anything that stalls the downloading of the CSS files? Like downloading something without async? Try putting the javascript files to the bottom of the body or add "defer" as an attribute to the script tags.

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for the reply. I find this problem weird, aswell. I updated my question with a little more info. I will check my javascript but afaik nothing is downloaded and not a lot of javascript is being executed for this particular page anyways.

Comment: Good. Hm, because of the time span between js and css it's easy to think that it's either JS doing something, or something CPU intensive for sending the css, like a preprocesser (LESS/SASS). Or maybe something is wrong with your bundeling? I'm just guessing here :) Try different browsers.

Comment: Not sure if that's what Tony meant, but could it be that the CSS files are loaded dynamically via JavaScript? You can simply test that by [deactivating JavaScript execution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994809). There are also some explanations for network request delays in [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35071691/432681).